# [Multi]DataTrigger "OR" statement?

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I want my image Visibility property set to Hidden when my bound table field

```
Weblink = NULL **OR** Weblink = ""
```

With MultiDataTrigger you can test several conditions in the following logic:

```
"IF FieldA = 1 **AND** FieldB = 2 THEN"
```

But what I need is

```
"IF FieldA = 1 **OR** FieldA = 2 THEN"
```

Here is part of my xaml whitch is only working when Weblink = ""; when Weblink = NULL my image stays visible

```
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Weblink}" Value="Null">
                <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Weblink}" Value="">
                <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Thanks in advance ! 
Spoelle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you wrote is equal to `Weblink == "Null"` but you need `Weblink == null`.

Try `Value="{x:Null}"` in the DataTrigger when the the Weblink property returns with null.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the `x:Null` markup extension, and for sake of clarity explicitly specify the empty string by using the `x:Static` markup extension:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Weblink}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Weblink}" Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}" >
    <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Hope this helps!